# How to enable the GPS location in android webview?

Tags: android, webview, gps, location

I tried hablitar the GPS location function for putting this in the manifest android:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and putting the webview settings this:

```
setGeolocationEnabled(true);
```

but still not working. What should I do to make it work? I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to begin requesting GPS updates in the code.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                              // Called when a new location is found by the location provider.
    }
}
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, locationListener);
```

You can then take the GPS values that you receive and pass them yo the webview through the URL

Comment: I do not understand what the URL and the code does not work because after the end of the second line is "() {" I get error

Comment: When you use a webview you will need to pass a URL to it to get it to display the page you are trying to view. From your question I assume you are trying to pass information to the page.

Comment: Please let me know if this resolved your questions and close that question or provide details if it did not.